# How to insert date in a specific format into a table in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

How can I insert the date into a table in a specific format like 'yyyy-mm-dd' and I need to retrieve values of the date column in the specified format mentioned above using `select` statement in which I should not use `to_date` or `to_char` conversion.

Comment: Dont, enter it in long, and translate it to what you need on upper layers. Globalization is a pain with code like this. It is terrible design to insert date as a string or a particular format to a db. But thats just me.

Answer (score 2):

You should not insert it with a different format, instead reformat the date whenever your going to use it

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS date FROM table;
// will give: day/month/year
```

I dont see why not to use TO_CHAR just because thats the way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Dates are stored as 7 bytes:

1. Century + 100
2. Year + 100
3. Month
4. Day of month
5. Hour + 1
6. Minute + 1
7. Second + 1

Century and year both have offsets (100) to allow negative century and year respectively(needed for BC dates). And hour, minute, second have offset +1 to ensure that the date itself can never contain NULL. We can use `dump` function to get internal representation of a date.

```
SQL> create table TB_Date(
  2    dt date
  3  )
  4  ;

Table created

SQL> insert into tb_date(dt) values(sysdate);

1 row inserted

SQL> commit;

Commit complete

SQL> select dump(dt) from tb_date;

DUMP(DT)
------------------------------------
Typ=12 Len=7: 120,112,11,1,9,49,26
```

Though in memory dates have a slightly different representation (8 bytes in length).

Having said that you cannot store dates (data of `DATE` datatype) in an specific format - you can display them in a specific format. And default format of how dates will be displayed is defined by `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter. Yes, you can store dates in a specific format in the column of `varchar2` datatype, but it highly discouraged and has a lot of disadvantages:

1. Extra computation. Every time you needed to implement dates arithmetic you would have to use implicit(not a good idea) or explicit(using `to_date` function)  datatype conversion.
2. Every time if a "date" have to be displayed in a different format you have to use `TO_CHAR(TO_DATE())` call.
3. What if date depends on time zone?

And many more.

So, store dates as values of `date` datatype and use `TO_CHAR()` function or `NLS_DATE_FORMA`T parameter to **display** dates in a desired format.